# DKIM SPF passes but mail goes to Spam Received: (from abc@localhost)

Tags: spam, postfix-mta, php, spam-prevention, dkim

I am facing an issue with the DKIM setup. We are sending newsletters which are going to spam in gmail.  The dkim & spf passes. Even the reverse dns is setup properly.  Below is a copy of mail headers that I see in gmail.

> Delivered-To: xyz@gmail.com
>   Received: by 10.112.29.116 with SMTP id j20csp27976lbh;
>          Tue, 2 Jul 2013 10:28:18 -0700 (PDT)
>   X-Received: by 10.50.11.103 with SMTP id p7mr22069045igb.24.1372786097413;
>          Tue, 02 Jul 2013 10:28:17 -0700 (PDT)
>
> Return-Path: 
>   Received: from mydomain.com (newsletter.mydomain.com. [108.171.163.8])
>          by mx.google.com with ESMTP id gu10si1702677icb.68.2013.07.02.10.28.16
>          for ;
>          Tue, 02 Jul 2013 10:28:17 -0700 (PDT)
>
> Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of abc@mydomain.com designates 108.171.163.8 as permitted sender) client-ip=108.171.163.8;
>   Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
>
> spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of abc@mydomain.com designates 108.171.163.8 as permitted sender) 
>   smtp.mail=abc@mydomain.com;  dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.com
>   Received: from mydomain.com (mydomain.com [127.0.0.1])
>     by mydomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 4A47318970;
>     Tue,  2 Jul 2013 17:30:38 +0000 (UTC)
>
> DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mydomain.com;
>     s=default; t=1372786238;
>     bh=s49+JPD0rpGLWWNhx0l6oMGPXzMHX4Adnh2xr6Q+4Iw=;
>     h=Date:Message-Id:To:Subject:MIME-Version:From:Content-Type;
>     b=NCmIyPQwp48nXJBpYdaVcmopJgOoLZ7H9KRcJ/o/HW2ZEZLRXreVwHRPWFI+s0h70
>      iVZPKVemBlAXtaL9T1hQOC61YVS//k3CEmUR732Axnz96dnJFbe5YtiD+mJN7dRZeL
>      Z7sf44NVi2E5EMWV7bi/RU7py0LNNo9Lp6KfzZLA=

Received: (from abc@localhost)
    by mydomain.com (8.14.5/8.14.5/Submit) id r62HUcoh028894;

> Tue, 2 Jul 2013 17:30:38 GMT
>   Date: Tue, 2 Jul 2013 17:30:38 GMT
>   Message-Id: <201307021730.r62HUcoh028894@mydomain.com>
>   To: xyz@gmail.com
>   Subject: mydomain | Subject Details
>   MIME-Version: 1.0
>   From: mydomain 
>   Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=np51d30e1a36dd3

I Think so the **Received: (from abc@localhost)** is causing the issue.

What I need to know how to resolve it. Instead of localhost it should use mydomain.com  This is my first time setting up such kind of server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the problem with the envelope sender and from address because,an email has two addresses associated with sending it: the envelope sender, and the From: address.  The envelope sender is where computers should respond (in the case of bounce messages or errors); the From: address is where people should respond.  In most cases, the envelope sender and the From: address match.Some case the Gmail put the mails which the 2 sender field did not match. You may try with the same.